# Curl not working with post param and application/json type

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying this command

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"user":[{"name":"name","phone_number":9934432222},{"name":"name","phone_number":9934432222},{"name":"name","phone_number":9934432222}]}' \
  http://local.com/apis/get_user_list
```

And printing data with `print_r($_POST);` but output is like

```
<pre>Array
(
)
```

Why its not printing post parameters?

I also tried with rest console, but in output of response header is like:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: text/html
```

And output is same empty.

Comment: 1) Why do you make a `POST` to a resource named `get_user_list`? That does not sound like REST. 2) Your curl usage looks correct, check the PHP side.

Comment: Its just name get_user_list but the functionality is like if we pass parameter with phone_numbers then it will search in db and will return those users. Can you give any suggestion what should i check in php side? because it should print there post parameters

Comment: Kindly post your Php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you POST data like JSON which isn't `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`, it may not be available in POST.

You can access the JSON using

```
$string = file_get_contents('php://input');

var_dump(json_decode($string));
```